# Redirect to Different Url From Asp.net mvc3 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i am woring on asp.net mvc3 and have a problem that i want to redirect user to any dynamic link which user entered , how to do this my current working is following

i tried by 2 types

**1.**

**Controller**

```
 if (condition == true)
        {
            string Link ="www.google.com";  // suppose this is the url entered by user
            ViewData["link"] = Link;
            return PartialView("REdirectToLink");
         }
```

**REdirectToLink.cshtml**

```
@{
  string link = ViewData["link"].ToString(); 
 }
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 var tlink = "@link";
 window.location.replace(tlink);
 </script>
```

**2.**

**Controller**

```
if (condition == true)
        {              
           string Link ="www.google.com"; // suppose this is the url entered by user
            return  RedirectPermanent(Link);// also tried return  Redirect(Link);
         }
```

how to do this , thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?  Is the redirect not working, or are you asking if there is a better way to do this?  And if it's the latter, I think your second solution is preferred over the first.

Comment: suppose my current location is "example.com/foo" , now when i call Redirect it put the url like this "example.com/www.google.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
string link = "http://www.google.com";
return Redirect(link);
```

Comment: mean ... suppose my current location is "example.com/foo" , now when i call Redirect it put the url like this "example.com/www.google.com"

Comment: do you put "http://" in the begining of the url? If you don't it would look like a relative url

Comment: Ohh My God ! ... it works when i include  "http://" ... Thanks @Bond ....Please put this as a answer

Comment: actually i didn't notice but Veblock also include "http://" . Thanks to both @Bond and veblock

Comment: You can also redirect relative URL with RedirectPermanent("/Something"); for example.